# desugaring for await .. of

Tags: javascript, async-await, for-await

Have been trying to figure out what exactly `for await .. of` does. However, even reading the specs I haven't been able to find exactly what it does.

Here is my guess:

```js
const it = iterable[Synbol.asyncIterator]();
while (true) {
  const { done, value } = await it.next();
  if (done) return;
  // User code...
}
```

However, if the iterator implements `return` and `throw` I'm not sure where/how they come into play?

One guess is:

```js
const it = iterable[Synbol.asyncIterator]();
try {
  while (true) {
    const { done, value } = await it.next();
    if (done) return;
    try { 
      // User code...
    } catch (err) {
      const { done } = await it.throw(err);
      if (done) return;
    }
  }
} finally {
  it.return();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `throw` method of the iterator is not used at all in the iteration protocol.

The `return` method of the iterator is called if the user code evaluates to an abrupt completion that prematurely ends the iteration (i.e. before `(await it.next()).done` is `true`):

- when the assignment to the iteration variables or the loop body throws an exception
- when the loop body evaluates a `return`, `break` or `continue outer_label` statement

The steps of the [*AsyncIteratorClose* procedure](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-asynciteratorclose) are really hard to accurately represent as JS code, so I'll avoid presenting an attempt at desugaring.

The `for await … of` steps are exactly those of the `for … of` loop, except for accessing the iterator by `Symbol.asyncIterator` instead of `Symbol.iterator`, and `await`ing the return values of `.next()` and `.return()` invocations.

Comment: As a bonus. What is `throw` intended for?

Comment: It is used by generators and `yield*`. You can direct generator functions through "injecting" arbitrary completions for the result of a `yield` expression: they can result in a value, they can behave as if a `return` was hit, or *they can throw* an exception.